# Filter Upper Case Letters and Lower Case Letters

Tags: qgis, filter

In a list of data i have uppercase letters and lowercase letters. I want to filter the data which contains only uppercase letters, lowercase later and mixed both upper and lower

**MM Metro** shoes are converting to **Mm Metro** when title the data set. For that I want to filter the data which is fully in uppercase or fully in lower case and mixed both upper and lower

I want to filter cases like (MOHAN METRO or mohan metro or mohan Metro or MOHAN metro) and want to change the filtered data. is there any possibility to filter that in QGIS

Comment: can you clarify what you want as output to all those cases?

Comment: @IanTurton i just want to filter the cases. thats it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just filter by comparison to their `UPPER` and `LOWER` transforms.

In the *Filter expression* dialog:

- filter for all-lower-case values

  ```
  "<field_name>" = LOWER("<field_name>")
  ```
- filter for all-upper-case values

  ```
  "<field_name>" = UPPER("<field_name>")
  ```
- filter for mixed-case values

  ```
  "<field_name>" NOT IN ( LOWER("<field_name>"), UPPER("<field_name>") )
  ```

Comment: Mixed means Both Upper and lower cases i.e. (Mohan METRO, Mohan metro). But it is filtering all the data which exclueds full upper and full lower cases